# How to handle non explicit errors inside sails.js helpers?

Tags: sails.js, waterline

I am trying to figure out how the Error handling in Sails.js works. Unfortunatley the code examples in the docs do not cover this use case.

The problem is I keep getting this error:

```
UsageError: `.intercept()` handler returned `undefined`, but this should never happen.
Regardless, here is a summary of the original underlying error:
```

Now all I am trying to do is call a helper and if it fails, then I want to catch the error (any), log it and run some code. If I wouldn't be using Sails but normal promises I would have handled it like this:

```
await helper().catch((err) => { // run some code }
```

In Sails I should be able to use [.intercept()](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/queries/intercept) instead of .catch()

My code looks like this:

```
// ExportController.js

        const csv = await sails.helpers.files.convertToCsv(data)
        .intercept((err) => {
            sails.log.error(err)
            req.addFlash('error_messages', 'Error parsing data to csv!')
            return res.redirect(`/`);
        })

// convert-to-csv.js

    if (!Array.isArray(inputs.data)) {
      throw new Error('invalid inputs.data type: ' +  typeof inputs.data)
    };
```

Now how can I avoid getting this error?
The [code examples](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/helpers/example-helper) show only cases where errors that are explicitly added to the exits object are handled, but not for general error handling.
[In the docs](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/queries/intercept) it says that if the filter argument is

> not provided, ALL errors will be intercepted.

Or is that only true for db queries? Because the .intercept() doc section is in that subcategory.

Answer (score 1):

You could use “throw ‘errorCode’;” for example:

Set the exits:

```
exits {
  errorWithCsvFile: {
    responseType: 'badRequest'
  }
}
```

```
const csv = await sails.helpers.files.convertToCsv(data)
  .intercept(‘somethingWrongCode’, ‘errorWithCsvFile’)
  ... // Other handles
  .intercept(err => new Error(err))
```

Alternative:

```
try {
  ...
  const csv = await sails.helpers.files.convertToCsv(data)
    .intercept((err) => {
      sails.log.error(err)
      req.addFlash('error_messages', 'Error parsing data to csv!')
      throw 'badRequest';
  })
  ...
} catch (err) {
  sails.log.err(err);
  return res.redirect(`/`);
}
```

Comment: ".intercept()` handler returned `undefined`, but this should never happen."